# how to use like syntax in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, find, sql-like

I am beginner using with php language and mysql for database.
this command not error but a variable cannot called

sorry I do not fluent english

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allBarang`($barang varchar(50))

BEGIN

SELECT nm_barang, harga,diskon,deskripsi,image,barang.id_kategori,jenis 
FROM barang    
INNER JOIN kategori on kategori.id_kategori = barang.id_kategori
Where nm_barang LIKE '%$barang%';

END
```

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: nope, variable not define

Comment: but I've done ^_^ just concat a variable with '%' on the front and back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `allBarang`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allBarang`(`$barang` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN    
  SELECT
    `nm_barang`,
    `harga`,
    `diskon`,
    `deskripsi`,
    `image`,
    `barang`.`id_kategori`,
    `jenis` 
  FROM `barang`
    INNER JOIN `kategori` ON `kategori`.`id_kategori` = `barang`.`id_kategori`
  WHERE `nm_barang` LIKE CONCAT('%', `$barang`, '%');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c168d/1)</kbd>